# ASP.NET website behaving differently when IIS is pointed at the source folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm working on an ASP.NET website that I inherited, and I'm trying to set it up so I can run it and debug it through my local Windows 10 IIS instance. To get it up and running in Visual Studio I had to remove and re-add references, because I was receiving a `Could not load file or assembly...` error.

It runs via Visual Studio now, but when I point IIS at the same folder I get the very same `Could not load file or assembly...` error. Where in IIS I would need to adjust to resolve this?

Comment: Is it a website? Or a Web application project? Does it have a .csproj file?

Comment: It's a website and not a web application, and there's no proj file

Comment: What file or assembly does it say it can't load?

Comment: LinkToExcel, the specific error I get when I turned on logging in the registry was `Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly`.

Comment: I also did a text content search of the entire solution for `.LinkToExcel,` to try to find where a binding may be referenced and didn't come up with anything

Comment: I figured out that problem at least. I had to enable 32 bit support, which I got from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745612/infamous-assembly-binding-error. Now I have a different issue I need to work through :o)

Comment: Post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this problem at least. I had to enable 32 bit support, which I got from this [Infamous assembly binding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745612/infamous-assembly-binding-error). Now I have a different issue I need to work through :o)